# Fixed menu link on iOS 15 only working after scrolling down

Tags: html, css, ios, responsive

I have what seems to be a simple issue with a website on iOS (testing on my up to date iPhone 13), but I just can't seem to find a fix that works. Starting to pull my hair out as it seems to be a bug rather than an actual issue with how I'm laying out the page.

The website has a very simple header that is fixed in position, which contains an absolutely positioned menu button on the right hand side. (Edit: just to clarify that the button triggers javascript to open a full height menu div that covers the left side of the window. All this part of the functionality works correctly, it's just that tapping on the button to open this navigation box does nothing until I scroll down)

On desktop using Chrome dev tools everything works fine at all browser sizes.

However, on iOS when loading the page the button is not clickable. If I scroll down slightly suddenly I can use it. Scroll back to the top and I can't use it anymore. This happens even if I remove all other content from the header leaving nothing but the menu button. I've tried everything I can think of but just can't get this button to work when the page hasn't been scrolled.

It seems like an issue of something covering the button, but there is nothing. Even with the header otherwise completely empty I get the same issue, and the content clearly can't be covering it as it visibly scrolls behind the header.

This is the css/html which I believe to be relevant: (#page contains the rest of the document and is padded to clear the fixed header. I have also tried removing the padding and using an extra div to push the content down as well just in case padding on a top level element was messing with things). `ui-container` is used to limit the width on large screens and simply has `width:100%` on smaller devices.

```
#top {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 10;
}
#header {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
#mobile-nav-btn {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 24px;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 22px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#page {
    padding-top: 113px;
}
```

```
  <body>
    <div id="top">
      <header>
        <div class="ui-container">
          <a id="mobile-nav-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
    <div id="page">
       ... content ...
    </div>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
<button onclick=“window.scrollTo(0, 500)”></button>
```

Comment: No, the menu button is fixed in the top right of the window and should bring up a navigation menu. Tapping on the button does nothing unless I scroll down the page slightly first, at which point it works as expected.

Comment: ok it’s easy to fix :D

Comment: I don't think you understand the issue. I don't want the button to scroll the page, it should (and does it most cases) open a navigation menu. However, if you open the page on iOS, tapping on the button does nothing. If you manually scroll down the page a small amount it suddenly starts working as expected.

Comment: oh i understand your issue now, but i tell you that i am coding ( now this device that and i am talking with you ) is Apple iPad IOS 15.3.1, uhh actually i dont have that problem, i think some of your code went wrong……

uhh 1 question : do you have js ( that’s about this? ) because only css and html is not enough to find the issue.

Comment: you could see there’s no issue in php, jQuery official website.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like it was the menu itself causing the problem as it was hidden using opacity and moved to `top: -100%` to get it out of the way. Seems that iOS messes around with the document height and this causes problems in some instances.

This may be specific to devices that have a rounded display, or may also affect all iOS devices as I know that the fact the address bar & navigation buttons auto shrink/hide on scroll can also play havoc with positioning.